# Javascript Set div name value?

Tags: javascript, html, function, random, set

I have made this random message displayer here:

```
<div class="MessageBar">

   <div id="Messages" name="Item">
      <div class="style9">
         Message 1
      </div>
   </div>

   <div id="Messages" name="Item">
      <div class="style7">
     Message 2
      </div>
   </div>

</div>


<script>
    var divs = document.getElementsByName('Item');

    for(var i=0;i<divs.length;i++)
        divs[i].style.display = 'none';
        var visibleDiv;

        setInterval(function () {

        var nextDiv;

        if(visibleDiv)
            visibleDiv.style.display = 'none';
            do
                {
                    nextDiv = divs[Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length)];
                }

    while(nextDiv == visibleDiv);
        visibleDiv = nextDiv;
        visibleDiv.style.display = 'block';
    },6000);

</script>
```

The 2 messages have a div name value set to "Item" for the script to randomize the messages. How could i set a div name value on a div with javascript so it will be added to the random messages when a function is called? Thanks!

Message 3 that i need to set the name value through javascript is like this:

```
<div id="Messages"> <<<---"Starts with no name value"
    <div class="style7">
    Message 3
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all: you cannot use the same id several times. This will be invalid code. You `class` instead of `id`.

Comment: And instead of `name` you could use another class like `randomMessage` and "ask" for them using `document.getElementsByClas('randomMessage')`. The third message has *Message* class at first and you can add the *randomMessage* class later if needed.